# Order a row or column in a table with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have been manually ordering columns in my table using AngularJS. Now I have the problem that I need to order the rows in a very specific way (much like the columns). Instead of making this table huge in the Html, I would rather ask around to see if there is a way that I could perhaps define an array in the .js script and have the columns/rows order themselves based on those arrays.

I have seen plenty of examples of how to sort alphabetically or by index but none so far that show how to sort by a predefined array.

Here is the table I am working with:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select ng-init="selectedRace='Human'" ng-model="selectedRace">
          <option ng-repeat="(raceName, item) in races">{{raceName}}</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <!--<th ng-repeat="(statGroup, item) in race.Attributes" class="{{statGroup}}">{{statGroup}}</th>-->
      <!--Going to manually type the column headers until I figure out how to sort via array or something-->
      <th>Starting Attribuites</th>
      <th>Hero Limit</th>
      <th>Epic Limit</th>
      <th>Veteran Limit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-model="race.Attributes">
    <tr ng-repeat="(statName, item) in race.Attributes['Starting Attributes']">
      <td class="statsDes">{{statName}}</td><!--These are not in proper order! I need to sort this via array or something-->
      <td class="Starting Attributes">{{race.Attributes['Starting Attributes'] | FilterSet:statName}}</td>
      <td>{{race.Attributes['Hero Limit'] | FilterSet:statName}}</td>
      <td>{{race.Attributes['Epic Limit'] | FilterSet:statName}}</td>
      <td>{{race.Attributes['Veteran Limit'] | FilterSet:statName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</br>
```

Any ideas? Other than doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything manually when you have AngularJS at your disposal.

AngularJS offers the `orderBy` filter to order an array by expression (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy).

If you need some feature that is not supported by the default `orderBy` filter, you can write your own custom filter to manipulate (sort) the array to your liking.

You can read more about custom filters on http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09.

Hope that helps!